# How to change action attribute in form element when I click the button?

Tags: php, html

In this code I have 3 button update,back,delete when I click anyone of it, $page should assign to action attribute in form element and post data should go based on which button is clicked.

```
<form action='<?php echo $page; ?>.php' method='post'>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $page='book_update';
}
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $page='book_delete';
}
if(isset($_POST['back']))
{
    $page='patientpage';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can access only to the data that were already sent by the browser in the request.

If you want to detect on which button is clicked, you can name your buttons, like this:

```html
<form action="/page.php" method="post" id="form_id">
  <input type="submit" value="edit" name="action">
  <input type="submit" value="delete" name="action">
  <input type="submit" value="back" name="action">
</form>
```

After click on the button, the form is submitted and you will find the value in PHP in `$_POST['action']`.

If you want to modify the `action` attribute dynamically based on the button **before the form is submitted**, you have to do with javascript, e.g. `document.getElementById('form_id').action = 'something-else.php';`